# Why does JSLint say there is a missing semicolon in this jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

Here are some JSLint results:

```
 1  finaffJS.module('custom_ribbon_buttons', ['jQuery'], function ($) {
 2      var my = {};
 3  
 4      my.insertLightBoxCloseDialog = function () {
 5          var url = $('#finaff-insert-lightbox-image-url').val();
 6          if (url) {
 7              var buttonHtml = '<a class="finaff-lightbox-link" href="' + encodeURI(url) + '"><div class="FinAff_View_Image_Button_Sprites FinAff_View_Image_Button">&#160;</div></a>';
 8              SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, buttonHtml);
 9          } else {
10              $('#finaff-insert-lightbox-image-url-flash').text('Need a URL');
11          }
12      }
13  
14      my.insertLightBoxClicked = function () {
    =^
    lint warning: missing semicolon
```

Where is the supposed missing semicolon?

Or why is JSLint confused?

Comment: Just because it's a function, doesn't mean it doesn't need a semi-colon. You're still setting a variable, and therefore should have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss semicolon in line 12:

```
 4      my.insertLightBoxCloseDialog = function () {
 5          var url = $('#finaff-insert-lightbox-image-url').val();
 6          if (url) {
 7              var buttonHtml = '<a class="finaff-lightbox-link" href="' + encodeURI(url) + '"><div class="FinAff_View_Image_Button_Sprites FinAff_View_Image_Button">&#160;</div></a>';
 8              SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, buttonHtml);
 9          } else {
10              $('#finaff-insert-lightbox-image-url-flash').text('Need a URL');
11          }
12      };
```

Take a look at the line 2, you are declaring a variable with a `{}`, and you put a semicolon. `insertLightBoxCloseDialog` also needs it, is the same.